# Ideas on how to display a list of user comments (UITableView vs UIScrollView vs ?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've worked with `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` but I've never worked with `UIScrollView` before which is what I think I should be using to display a (potentially long) vertical list of user comments from an array.

I was thinking of either using `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` but wasn't sure which was better to use over the other. I'm familiar with `UITableView` but not `UIScrollView` so I don't know how I'd go about listing and displaying comments in a `UIScrollView`. E.g. what do I need to add to the `UIScrollView` to make it display an array of user comments? Is it a Web View (I haven't used a Web View before)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an array of comments, it sounds logical to use a `UITableView` (or `UICollectionView`), as otherwise, you would need to manager view creation and release by yourself. `UITableView` is a in fact a `UIScrollView` implementation, with the view management done for you.

UIScrollView can be difficult to manage by yourself. It is a blank canvas where you can add views, but how many views do you want to have at one time? No point in loading all the comments at once. So you'd want a system that would track the scroll position, and dynamically load and unload necessary and unnecessary views, which is exactly what table views and collection views do.

Just make sure to not fall for the `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView` trap. This is never recommended, and can be hazardous for memory management (as more than necessary views or cells can be loaded, which, depending on the number of comments, can be a lot). If you are currently using a scroll view to display your view, you can convert that to one or more views and then set them as the top cells of the table view, with the comments taking the lower cells.

Comment: Hi Leo, I was in the process of adding a UITableView into a UIScrollView, thank you for saving me time! After reading the comments here, a standard UICollectionView seems right.

Comment: UICollectionView is a good choice, but remember, it is only available for iOS6. If that is good enough for you, great.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with UITableView, especially if the array of comments is long. Tables support cell reuse which will help keep down the memory footprint. By that I mean that if properly configured, as soon as a cell goes out the top of the screen while scrolling down, it will come out of the bottom with new content.

Table view's also have the benefit of easily being able to animate new rows if you want to add to the table after the fact:

```
[<#(UITableView *)#> insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>];
```

And operations to automatically scroll a specific cell to top, bottom, center, etc.

```
[<#(UITableView *)#> scrollToRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> atScrollPosition:<#(UITableViewScrollPosition)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Additionally, if you go the table view route there are some projects on implementing a Messages app inspired bubble style chat log on [CocoaControls.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chat). I believe all of these projects use table views.